# Paho-mqtt with asyncio library

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, python-asyncio, paho

I want to implement paho-mqtt in which it should process the incoming messages asynchronously.

I have implement gmqtt with asyncio which runs perfectly fine, but as far as I understand paho-mqtt is better to use rather than gmqtt (Link : https://www.emqx.io/blog/comparision-of-python-mqtt-client).

gmqtt w/ asyncio :

```
def assign_callbacks_to_client(self, client):
    """ Helper function which sets up client's callbacks. """
    client.on_connect = self.on_connect
    client.on_message = self.on_message
    client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
    client.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe

async def subscriber(self, mqtt_name):
    """ Connect to mqtt-broker. """
    sub_client = MQTTClient(mqtt_name)
    self.assign_callbacks_to_client(sub_client)
    logging.info("connecting")
    await sub_client.connect(host=config.MQTT_HOST, port=int(config.MQTT_PORT))
    return sub_client
```

could you please let me know, how to implement paho with asyncio library?
Will using loop_start asynchronously, as I understand everytime it executes it starts a new thread in background.

Answer (score 2):

`loop_start()` only create a single background thread that all the callbacks will be run on, you should not be doing long running tasks directly in these callbacks as they will block all other actions of the client.

If you want to process incoming messages without blocking then you will need to implement your own thread pool and just use the `on_message()` callback to push messages to this thread pool.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to own implement thread pool, as I am new to this? Would it implement using threading?

Comment: Does paho-mqtt fully supports MQTT 5.0 protocol?

Comment: Does paho-mqtt fully supports MQTT 5.0 protocol?
In my application, I'm using MQTT 5.0 protocol so which is best in python paho-mqtt or gmqtt (with asyncio)?

Comment: That is a totally separate question and as for which is best, that is off topic for Stack Overflow as it is entirely dependent on your use case and opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [aiomqtt](https://sbtinstruments.github.io/aiomqtt/). aiomqtt combines the stability of the time-proven paho-mqtt library with an intuitive, idiomatic asyncio interface.